# Buffering stdout / stderr from child process

Tags: node.js

Say I launch a child process with a reasonable amount of stdout/stderr:

```
const k = cp.spawn('bash');

k.stdout.pause();
k.stderr.pause();

setTimeout(function(){
  // 20  seconds later, we resume streaming
 k.stdout.pipe(getDest());
 k.stderr.pipe(getDest());
},20000);
```

with the stdout/stderr for this child process really get buffered in memory and will none of it be lost when I finally resume streaming?

Comment: Have you tried it to see? Seems rather easy to test

Comment: There are some edge cases, like if the child process exits before 20 seconds elapses.

Comment: I doubt that would matter, but it might

Comment: Yeah I have tried it, and so far it works, I came here to see if someone knows why it might fail in a certain case, and to perhaps explain more about what's happening. It looks like `k.stdout.resume()` is automatically called when `pipe()` is called with `k.stdout`.